# How is __builtin__ made available at runtime?

Tags: python

Why does the first statement return `NameError`, while `max` is available

```
>>> __builtin__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__builtin__' is not defined
>>> max
<built-in function max>
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.max
<built-in function max>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The builtins namespace associated with the execution of a code block is actually found by looking up the name `__builtins__` in its global namespace; this should be a dictionary or a module (in the latter case the module’s dictionary is used). By default, when in the `__main__` module, `__builtins__` is the built-in module `__builtin__` (note: no ‘s’); when in any other module, `__builtins__` is an alias for the dictionary of the `__builtin__` module itself. `__builtins__` can be set to a user-created dictionary to create a weak form of restricted execution.

So really it is looking up `__builtins__` (since you are in the main module)

```
>>> __builtins__.max
<built-in function max>
```

But as mentioned above, this is just an alias for `__builtin__` (which isn't part of the main module's namespace, although it has been loaded and referenced by `__builtins__`).

Answer (score 4):

`__builtin__` is just a way to import/access the pseudo module in case you want to replace or add a function that is always globally available. You do not need to import it to use the functions. But `__builtin__` itself does not exist on `__builtin__` so it is not available without importing it first.

See [the python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) for more information about this module.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `import __builtin__` in order for all the [built-in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) names to be available.  But you do need to import it in order for the name `__builtin__` to be available in the scope of your code.